# Get the Playlist embedded in Post/Page content

Tags: media, playlist

I often use **get_media_embedded_in_content** to get the audio or video embedded inside post or page content. But it doesn't seem to work with playlist.
I have tried this code

```
$main_content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
$media = get_media_embedded_in_content( $main_content, array(
    'audio',
    'video',
    'playlist',
) );
```

And nothing inside the audio tag:

```
 string '<audio controls="controls" preload="none" width="618"></audio>'
```

Is it possible to do that? Thanks for all your helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_media_embedded_in_content()` uses a regex to match the input tags, but the HTML for playlists is not made from a single tag, instead it's constructed with tags like `<div>`, `<script>`, `<noscript>`, `<ol>`, `<li>`.

Recently I posted an answer to [get post playlist like get_post_gallery()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/273940/get-post-playlist-like-get-post-gallery/273994#273994) that you can check out, to see if it helps. It introduces the custom `wpse_get_post_playlists()` function.

We could of course target these parts:

```
<div class="wp-playlist...">...</div>
```

with regular expression, but then we have to note that the first instance can contain a script part above it, like:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script>document.createElement('audio');</script><![endif]-->
```

Another approach is to wrap the output from playlist shortcodes, with e.g.

```
<!--wpse-playlist--> ... <!--/wpse-playlist-->
```

and then use regular expression to extract only these parts within.

Here's an example how to wrap the output of playlist shortcodes:

```
add_shortcode( 'playlist', function( $attr = [], $content = null )
{
    return sprintf( 
        '<!--wpse-playlist-->%s<!--/wpse-playlist-->',
        wp_playlist_shortcode( $attr )
    );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! The custom functions helps me indeed. I'm still not clear about the second method,however, I will take a deeper look at it. Thanks again.

Comment: Is it safe to use **do_shortcode_tag** ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode_tag) in the custom function for my theme? If not, can you recommend another function? Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. You could use the callback directly, i.e . [`wp_playlist_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_playlist_shortcode/), instead of parsing the shortcode.